# How can I read the Javadocs?

Tags: graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I went all over the forums and I found a question similar to mine but it didn't answer my question that I'm about to ask.

```html
public class DrawSomething extends JPanel {

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g); //how is an object passed in that parameter?
  super.paintComponent(g); //I don't get how that works
  this.setBackground(Color.white);
```

Again, I'm lost as to how the code above gives the functionality to draw something on the JPanel.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g);
```

That above line of code should be a method you override. So it shouldn't just end with a semicolon. But I'll just shrug it off. I will try to make this as simple as possible. In your program, you create a JPanel and when you add that to a JFrame. The JFrame will know you have added a JPanel. The programmers who coded the JFrame will know the JPanel has a paintComponent method and will call it and pass in the Graphics object. Furthermore, now that it is calling a method you have overriden it will run any code you have in there.

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

When you override the code, you are erasing whatever was there before and putting your new code in. That means all the old code is gone but when you call the super.paintComponent(g); you are basically saying, run the old code and my code.

You should get a grasp on OOP concepts and the way objects and their methods interact with eachother. Knowing how to develop an application will make it easier for you to use another person's code. You can start [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-oops-concepts).

Answer (score 0):

The class DrawSomething would define method paintComponent. Calling paintComponent on an object that is of class DrawSomething would execute that method. You haven't defined your method, but if you did, that method's code would be run.

The keyword "super" allows you to reference to a method of the parent class, in this case JPanel. This is useful when you want to extend of a method of a parent: have it do the same thing and something extra. Note that you can't use this directly in  a class definition the way you have, you have to put it in a method.